# Problem on Stack Exchange, PC and Mobile View

Tags: discussion, support, mobile-web, stack-exchange

In `top tag` in profile activity this will load on a PC:

[image: PC]

And in Mobile view

[image: Mobile]

You can clearly notice there is conflict on there.

Questions are

1. Why is that??
2. I need four more to earn the **bronze badge in the PHP** tag when I look at mobile. So on a PC there is 7 more to go. So if I earn four points will I get the badge or do I need 7?
3. Which one is correct? Mobile or web?

Comment: I blame caching...

Comment: i clear all data and check still same

Answer (score 2):

I blame caching ...

I also blame [server side caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) ...

At the server all pages are heavily cached, some pages for a very long time because it takes a lot of time to get all the data. Those page are completely stored at the server and then served on request to multiple users. It doesn't require a round-trip to the database but it does show you stale data.

The app on the other hand uses a different data path which might involve different cache strategies. That explains the differences.

For further reading:

- [Does Stack Exchange use caching and if so, how?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-exchange-use-caching-and-if-so-how)
- [What is caching, and where is it used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178596/what-is-caching-and-where-is-it-used)
- [Stack Exchange data access and caching coding practices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239480/stack-exchange-data-access-and-caching-coding-practices)
- [Browser caching has become a bit too aggressive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237600/browser-caching-has-become-a-bit-too-aggressive)
- [How does StackOverflow handle cache invalidation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/how-does-stackoverflow-handle-cache-invalidation)
- [Caching (“caching, it's always caching”)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414)